# Samsung Privileged Health SDK - Increase the accelerometer data frequency per second

Tags: android, wear-os, samsung

The FAQs on the Samsung forum state:

The accelerometer tracking provided by the Samsung Privileged Health SDK records data samples with 25Hz resolution in batches of 12 seconds (300 samples). Batching reduces battery consumption and enables you to track data over longer durations.

We have a requirement to collect data at a frequency of 50Hz per second. I see no customization available for that. Is there a way I can request more records per second?